# Time_Series_mean of every 10min data

Tags: python-3.x

I have the data like follows:

```
df.index value
2019-02-28 00:00:00 101
2019-02-28 00:10:00 97
2019-02-28 00:20:00 97
2019-02-28 00:30:00 96
2019-02-28 00:40:00 110
2019-02-28 00:50:00 117
2019-02-28 01:00:00 121
2019-02-28 01:10:00 114
2019-02-28 01:20:00 112
2019-02-28 01:30:00 103
2019-02-28 01:40:00 104
2019-02-28 01:50:00 105
2019-02-28 02:00:00 106
2019-02-28 02:10:00 104
2019-02-28 02:20:00 103
2019-02-28 02:30:00 97
2019-02-28 02:40:00 101
2019-02-28 02:50:00 103
2019-02-28 03:00:00 102
2019-02-28 03:10:00 101
```

Is there to method helping me to make a new dataframe resampled by 15min, where for full hours and 30min takes value from above data and for 15min (the average of 10 and 20) and similarly for 45 (the average of 40 and 50)? Additionally how to check if the dataframe starts with full hour?

The part of the code I tried to use is

> df_15=pd.date_range(start=df.index[0], end=df.index[-1], freq='15T')
> df_15=df_15.to_frame(index=False)

```
> for row in range(0,len(df_15+1),6):
> mean=df.iloc[row]
> df_mean=pd.concat([df_mean,mean])
> mean=(df.iloc[row+1]+df.iloc[row+2])/2
> df_mean=pd.concat([df_mean,mean])
> mean=df.iloc[row+3]
> df_mean=pd.concat([df_mean,mean])
> mean=(df.iloc[row+4]+df.iloc[row+5])/2
> df_mean=pd.concat([df_mean,mean])
```

> 

but I get an error
TypeError: Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with DatetimeArray is no longer supported. Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * obj.freq`

Comment: Use `resample` to aggregate to the bucket?

Comment: Do you have any mode precise hint? I don't get your point. Thank you for help :)

Comment: `dataf.resample("15min").sum()` for example this sums data in 15 minutes buckets

Comment: Ok, that's right, but the thing is that I want just to make mean of 10 and 20, leaving full hour and 30min without changes